# Gulp webserver, What is the filter?

Tags: javascript, filter, webserver, gulp

I'm following a tutorial series, And I'm familiar with the principles of Gulp but

> I can't seem to find **what the Filter function does** in the following example

The example is also shown here, but no further explanation is provided
https://github.com/hiddentao/gulp-server-livereload#how-can-i-pass-a-custom-filter-to-livereload

This is the code.

```
gulp.task('serve', function(done) {
  gulp.src('')
    .pipe(server({
      livereload: {
        enable: true,
        filter: function(filePath, cb) {
          if(/main.js/.test(filePath)) {
            cb(true)
          } else if(/style.css/.test(filePath)){
            cb(true)
          }
        }
      },
      open: true
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The filter gives you the ability to **exclude files in your project directory that my change (e.g. git files), but your server does not autmatically reloads**. You may define arbitrary logic in this function.

**Longer answer:**

The filter defines a function that gets the `filePath` of the file that changed and the predefined callback function `cb` that triggers a reload:

```
function (shouldReload) {
  if (shouldReload) {
    gutil.log('Livereload: file changed: ' + filename);

    config.livereload.io.sockets.emit('reload');
    // Treat changes to sourcemaps as changes to the original files.
    filename = filename.replace(/\.map$/, '');

    config.livereload.io.sockets.emit('file_changed', {
      path: filename,
      name: path.basename(filename),
      ext: path.extname(filename),
    });
  }
}
```

That means if you call `cb(true)` a live reload of your server is done.

As I read your example you want to **reload your server only if the files `main.js` and `style.css` are changed**. Therefore escape the `.` by `\.` which might match any character (see regex):

```
if(/main\.js/.test(filePath)) {
  cb(true)
} else if(/style\.css/.test(filePath)){
  cb(true)
}
```

That means execute this task. Saving and changing either `main.js` or `style.css` will trigger a live reload of the server.

My server gets stuck sometimes and does not reload. Pressing one time CTRL+C helps getting him back to work ;-)